# Iterate over two uneven lists and stop once the second list ends

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, a list of languages (long list) and a list of word (has 6 items). I need to print each word next to a language but stop it once all 6 items are printed.

> at first, I ran this code and it works fine (print 6 times), but as far as I add new a language, it would the last item in (texts) and that added language.

```
langs = ['russian', 'spanish', 'german', 'italian', 'english', 'english']
texts = ['technology', 'communism', 'community', 'university', 'computer', 'politics']        

for a, lang in enumerate(langs, start=1):
    for b, text in enumerate(texts, start=1):
        if b == a:  
            break
    print(text, '->', lang)
```

I think it is very easy, but I could not figure it out yet.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be just looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for lang, text in zip(langs, texts):
    print(text, '->', lang)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I need. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The functionality that you require is exactly what `zip` does in Python.

> `zip()` - Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

```
langs = ['russian', 'spanish', 'german', 'italian', 'english']
texts = ['technology', 'communism', 'community', 'university', 'computer', 'politics'] 

print(list(zip(langs, texts)))
```

```
Output:

[('russian', 'technology'), ('spanish', 'communism'), ('german', 'community'), ('italian', 'university'), ('english', 'computer')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to use here is `zip()`

```
for i,j in zip(langs,texts):
    print(i," ---> ",j)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is to use zip as already mentioned in the other answers. However, if you can't use the zip function, switch the loops around. However, `if b == a: break`  will always break after the first iteration.
So, try:

```
for b, text in enumerate(texts, start=1):
    for a, lang in enumerate(langs, start=1):
        print(text, '->', lang)
```

OR

```
for a, lang in enumerate(langs, start=1):
    for b, text in enumerate(texts, start=1):
        if a == len(b):
            break
        print(text, '->', lang)
```

Answer (score 0):

zip function is perfect for this purpose:

```
for lang, text in zip(langs, texts):
    print(text, '->', lang)
```